# Airflow executing same operator twice

Tags: airflow

I am using Airflow 1.8.0 with the LocalExecutor and I have a daily DAG running various Redshift queries using the postgres_operator to insert some rows in a table.
I just noticed that sometimes, for a given TaskInstance, the postgres_operator is launched twice so in the end I have duplicates in my table.

When I look at the logs of the TaskInstance I see something like that for the problematic taskInstances: "Starting attempt 1 of 2" happens twice in the same second (without automatic retry involved or manual interference):
[image: log_airflow]

Do you know where the problem could come from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running multiple scheduler daemons? Even if you have multiple Airflow workers, you should only have one daemon process for all your machines.

Comment: Thanks! How can I check that please? I am using only one machine by the way (localexecutor).

Comment: Look for running processes with `ps aux` on your machine

Comment: Thanks Antoine! When I do this I get like 50 lines with 'airflow scheduler',  maybe we are doing something wrong when we deploy changes.

Comment: We are using supervisord, it seems we need to specify some settings like https://gist.github.com/criccomini/1d50130d32db0a61905ec4e65b55c32d

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it looks like this happens on startup so the task may be backfilling.

As an asside, it's a good practice to create idempotent DAGs by using the `execution_date` in your logic. Airflow may be running them twice in an attempt to "catchup." From the [Backfill and Catchup](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup) section in the Airflow Docs:

> A key capability of Airflow is that these DAG Runs are atomic,
>   idempotent items, and the scheduler, by default, will examine the
>   lifetime of the DAG (from start to end/now, one interval at a time)
>   and kick off a DAG Run for any interval that has not been run (or has
>   been cleared). This concept is called Catchup.

When we got started, we had a similar issue.